# How do I make gravity ball stop from sinking? Javascript SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg

The ball bounces just fine but once it starts to decelerate it starts sinking beyond the SVG border.
I just don't know how to fix this

Preview images:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8lyG.jpg

Dropbox of the project folder(you need to install "Web Server For Chrome" extension and run the html file through the Web Server extension):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/sta0tqjs9awvwro/JS%20circleGravity%20Oct13.zip?dl=0

Code:

Sprite.js:

```
export default class sprite {
    constructor(shape, x, y, dx, dy, width, height) {
        this.shape = shape
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
        this.dx = dx
        this.dy = dy
        this.width = width
        this.height = height
    }
    move() {
        this.x += this.dx
        this.y += this.dy
        //did we hit the svg edge?
        //if so, which one, and then bounce
        if(this.x + this.shape.radius > this.width){
            this.dx *= -1
        }
        if (this.y + this.shape.radius > this.height){
            this.dy *= -1
        }
        if (this.x - this.shape.radius < 0){
            this.dx *= -1
        }
        if (this.y - this.shape.radius < 0){
            this.dy *= -1
        }
        this.shape.showAt(this.x, this.y)
        //simulate gravity
        this.dy += 1;
    }
}
```

Shape.js:

```
export default class Shape {
    constructor(type, svg, color, onclick) {

        this.svg = svg
        this.color = color
        const html = `<${type} fill="${this.color}" />`
        this.svg.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html)
        this.shape = this.svg.lastChild
        this.shape.addEventListener('click', onclick)
    }



    get svg() {
        return this._svg
    }
    set svg(value) {
        if (!value) {
            return
        }
        this._svg = value
    }

    get shape() {
        return this._shape
    }

    set shape(value) {
        if (!value) {
            return
        }
        this._shape = value
    }

    get color() {
        return this._color
    }

    set color(value) {
        if (typeof (value) !== 'string' || value.length !== 7) {
            return
        }
        this._color = value
    }


    showAt(x, y) {
        this.shape.setAttribute('display', 'block')
    }

}
```

game.js:

```
import Rec from './Rec.js'
import sprite from './Sprite.js'
import Circle from './Circle.js'

export default class Game {
    constructor(svg) {
        this.score=0
        this.svg = svg
        this.sprite = new sprite(
            new Circle(this.svg, 20, '#fc03a5', this.onclick),
            200,
            200,
            0,
            //Math.random() * 20 - 10,
            0,
            this.svg.getBoundingClientRect().width,
            this.svg.getBoundingClientRect().height,
        )
    }

    onclick = () => {
        this.score++
        console.log(this.score)
        document.getElementById('score').value = this.score
    }

    play() {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.sprite.move()
        }, 10);
    }

    get score() {
        return this._score
    }
    set score(value) {
        if (typeof (value) !== 'number') {
            return
        }
        this._score = value
    }
    get svg() {
        return this._svg
    }
    set svg(value) {
        if (!value) {
            return
        }
        this._svg = value
    }
}




const init = () => {
    const svg = document.getElementById("mySvg")
    const game = new Game(svg)
    game.play()
}
```

Circle.js:

```
import Shape from './Shape.js'

export default class Circle extends Shape {
    constructor(svg, radius, color, onclick) {
        super('circle', svg,color,onclick)
        this.radius = radius
        this.shape.setAttribute("r", this.radius)
    }
    get radius() {
        return this._radius
    }
    set radius(value) {
        if (typeof (value) !== 'number') {
            return
        }
        this._radius = value
    }
    showAt(cx, cy) {
        this.shape.setAttribute('cx', cx)
        this.shape.setAttribute('cy', cy)
    }
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <style>
        * {
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }
        svg{
            background-color: aqua
        }
    </style>
</head>
<html>

<body>
    <div>


        <label for="score">Score</label>
        <input type="text" readonly id="score" value="0"> <br>
        <svg id="mySvg" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
        </svg>
    </div>
    <script type="module">
        import Game from './Game.js'
        const svg = document.getElementById("mySvg")
        const game = new Game(svg)
        game.play()
    </script>    

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: add some code here please.

Comment: Not everyone uses Chrome or wants to use Dropbox. Add the part of not-working code into your question please

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenience. This is my first post ever on Stackoverflow. I edited the post appropriately.

Comment: Please post a minimal example of the code here that reproduces the problem.  Go ahead and _include_ a link to something like jsbin for convenience (and not dropbox and definitely not requiring any extension), but do ensure the code in your question is also runnable (and a single file if possible -- questions with multiple code files are much less likely to get answered)